# Should I put /var in a separate partition for a database server?

Tags: server, partitioning, database

I will be using a Ubuntu server install as a server for a MySQL database. Is there any benefit to having `/var` in a separate partition from the root file system?

Comment: See also a [question on separate partitions generally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685/176171) and questions specific to [/boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256/176171) and [/tmp](https://superuser.com/q/442383/499711)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always have `/var` on a separate partition and never had problems with it. Doing it this way prevents a misbehaving application (like your database server, but also log files in `/var/log`) from eating up all the space on the disk. Of course it also works the other way around. If someone (or some program) decides to write enormous files in `/tmp` this would affect your database as well if `/tmp` and `/var` reside on the same partition.

If you plan on putting parts of your directory hierarchy on different partitions I would suggest to take a look at LVM (the Logical Volume Manager). LVM allows you to dynamically extend your 'partitions' (called Logical Volumes or LVs in LVM parlance). This means that if your LV containing `/var/` is almost full you can extend it, grow the file system on the fly and continue without any interruption to your database.

Comment: How would /tmp and /var exist on the same partition? They would be symlinks to a different mount point for that partition... or can you actually add two entries into fstab specifying a specific directory in a partition to mount.

Comment: `/tmp` and `/var` are always on the same partition (namely the one `/` is on) unless you specify either of them is on a separate partition. For example, if you decide to only have two partitions, e.g. `/` and `/home` then `/tmp` and `/var` are on the same partition.

Comment: Oh, I see. It sounded like you had a partition where -only- `/tmp` and `/var` resided.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to run one of my natty servers with a separate /var a couple of weeks before - it just doesn't start.
There seems to be a pretty long history of [Ubuntu having various problems with /var on a separate filesystem](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=separate%20/var)

So, your best bet is to have some separate data partition, just not put there your entire /var

Answer (score -1):

You could either make a symlink or just mount the partition as /var. If you want to mount it as /var you'll need to specify that in /etc/fstab.

Comment: While this may be a valid consideration, it just adds confusion and is not relevant to the context of the question.